# Microsoft Report viewer error

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, reportviewer

Very simple and short question: I'm trying to create a report with report viewer in Visual Studio 2015. I add the rdlc-file using the Report Wizard, and then I need to choose a data set. I selected the "Object" option, since I get my data from a WCF service, so I want to point to a DTO class that I use just for that. All fine so far. Then I get the list of assemblies I can pick from, and there I just select the class I want. I click Finish, and then I get the following error message:

[image: Error]

Now, the real nasty thing is: it works in other solutions, just not the one I'm working in... I project I'm working in is a WPF project. Now, I tried doing the same thing in a WPF project in another solution, no issue. I tried a WinForms project in the solution it's not working in, same error. I tried doing the same thing in other solutions using other .NET frameworks, or the same .NET framework (4.6.1), no issue whatsoever. Anyone got any ideas? It's driving me up the wall!

Comment: You have to do operation in proper order. You can have problem if you modify the data format as RDLC might be out of synch with source data. I don't remember exactly how to do things as some time has elapsed but when you do a lot of changes, you get to know in which order to make changes and when to compile...

Comment: You might debug Visual Studio using another instance to see from where the error come... Don't know if it works for RDLC. I have used that tricks a few time with WinForms when a form could not be loaded in the designer.

Comment: Clean your solution and rebuild it. If it works in a new solution but not the current one and you are not able to figure out why, then the easiest solution would be to move the old code in the new solution.

Comment: Worked after "messing around" a bit and doing some rebuilding, cleaning up. Thx guys!